# HMAC SHA256 in .NET .1.1

Tags: c#, asp.net, sha256, hmac, .net-1.1

I have to dare with a web application developed in **.NET 1.1 Framework**, with no possibilities to upgrade to major versions.

Having said that, I need to encrypt a text using **HMAC SHA256**.

I see that System.Security.Cryptography namespace in .NET 1.1 provides me a way to has a message in SHA256. But I need to use HMAC (Hash-based Message Authentication Code) with SHA256, so I send **not only the text to encrypt, but also a key**.

I see that .NET Framework 2.0 and later has an specific class HMACSHA256 to manage this. But **haven't found an implementation for .NET 1.1.**

¿Any help?

Thanks in advance

Comment: iirc .net has access to any encryption stuff installed on the machine, including all the CNG stuff... But you do have to specifically name what you are using

Comment: Conclusion: Finally I used the answer in this link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21498696/try-to-code-hmac-sha256-using-c-net . It has some sintax from .NET 3.5, but it's easy to adapt, and it worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

You can add to your project the file from [Microsoft](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/security/cryptography/hmacsha256.cs,fbe807e4ab1f7871,references):

```
namespace System.Security.Cryptography {
    [System.Runtime.InteropServices.ComVisible(true)]
    public class HMACSHA256 : HMAC {
        //
        // public constructors
        //

        public HMACSHA256 () : this (Utils.GenerateRandom(64)) {}

        public HMACSHA256 (byte[] key) {
            m_hashName = "SHA256";

#if FEATURE_CRYPTO
            m_hash1 = GetHashAlgorithmWithFipsFallback(() => new SHA256Managed(), () => HashAlgorithm.Create("System.Security.Cryptography.SHA256CryptoServiceProvider"));
            m_hash2 = GetHashAlgorithmWithFipsFallback(() => new SHA256Managed(), () => HashAlgorithm.Create("System.Security.Cryptography.SHA256CryptoServiceProvider"));
#else
            m_hash1 = new SHA256Managed();
            m_hash2 = new SHA256Managed();
#endif // FEATURE_CRYPTO

            HashSizeValue = 256;
            base.InitializeKey(key);
        }
    }
}
```

It seems that all calls are based on class that exists in .Net 1.1

Comment: Thanks Thomas ! I'm taking a look right now. Think I would probably had to add also HMAC base class. I'll tell you if this works

Comment: Uff ! This can be hard... one class inherit from other, and that one from other, etc. etc. :)

Comment: @Javier yes but `KeyedHashAlgorithm` is available in .Net 1.1 (good news :p )

Comment: I'm trying to take that code into my own classes, but not sure If it finally will work. Anyway, I'll keep tryning. I'll tell you how this ends. Anyway, thanks very much, you have my positive vote!

Comment: I'm giving a chance to this post:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21498696/try-to-code-hmac-sha256-using-c-net

It uses some features from major versions of .NET than 1.1, but it's easy to adapt. I'll trying it now...

Comment: Just some feedback: by the moment I'm having good results using the answer linked in my previous comment. I'll put here the conclusion when I'm 100% it works for me. Thank you.

Comment: @Javier glad to hear that it (almost) works for you !

Comment: Finally I used the answer in this link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21498696/try-to-code-hmac-sha256-using-c-net . It has some sintax from .NET 3.5, but it's easy to adapt, and it worked for me !. Thanks very much Thomas